# How can I get an element containing exactly the specified text using JQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a list each containing a text value. How do I get the list object having exactly a given text value?

```
<div id="child4"></div>

<div id="child5">ib</div>

<div id="child6"></div>

<div id="child7">ii</div>

<div id="child8">iii</div>
<div id="child1" width="200px"></div><div id="child2">i</div>

 <script type="text/javascript">
    alert($("div>div:contains('i')").attr("id"));
 </script>
```

The above script gives me all the div that contains the text value i..How can I fix this so that i get an element having exactly the same text value as 'i'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$("div > div").filter(function() {
   return $(this).text() === "i"; 
});
```

The `filter` method returns only elements that match the condition. The condition will only match elements whose `text` is the specified string.

Note that in your example, this will not match anything, as your selector `div > div` will select `div` elements that are direct children of another `div`, and  the elements in your example have no parent `div`.

Here's an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/3wEwp/1/) of the code running. In the example, I've changed the selector to just `div`.

Comment: It's the strict equality operator. It prevents JavaScript converting between types. In this case, it makes no difference, you could just as easily use `==`, but it's good practice to use it when you don't want type coercion to occur. For more info, see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/523643/difference-between-and-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

use fallowing code-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert($("div>div:contains('\\s*i\\s*$')").attr("id"));
 </script>
```

Comment: It says i is undefined ..What does the \\s* stand for by the way?

Answer (score 1):

This is one way:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     $("div").each(function() {
         if ($(this).text() == 'i')
             alert($(this).attr('id')); 
        })
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can extend jQuery's selector engine to add a new selector:

```
$.expr[':'].texteq = function( elem, i, match, array ) {
    return $(elem).text() === match[3];
};

alert($("div:texteq('i')").attr("id"));
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/cZWSP/)