# How to search a text in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, text, full-text-search

i have a question that if i want to search a perticular text in any page using jquery. what i don't want is that

```
<p id="1">iii</p>
<p id="2">i</p>
<p id="3">ibiib</p>
<p id="4">bb</p>
<p id="5">tina</p>

 <script type="text/javascript">
    console.log($("div:contains('i')"));
 </script>
```

this above code gives me all paragraphs except id=4; but what i want is only paragraph with id=2 to be selected.
if there is a way to do that in javascript or any other library reply me...

Comment: Do you want to for the full content of elements, or for words?

Comment: Exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7076159/how-can-i-get-an-element-containing-exactly-the-specified-text-using-jquery/7076346#7076346

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend jQuery's selector engine to add a new one:

```
$.expr[':'].texteq = function( elem, i, match, array ) {
    return $(elem).text() === match[3];
};

console.log($('p:texteq(i)'));
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/9DvT6/3/)

Comment: very nice :) I would call it `:exact` (+1)

Comment: @karim79 I wanted to convey the idea that it uses `$().text` and not `$().html`, `$().val` or whatever.

Answer (score 5):

Use [$.filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter#using-filter-function).

This will return the `div`s, which contains just one `i`.

```
$('div').filter(function () {
    return $(this).html() == 'i';
});
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$('p').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() === 'i';
});
```

Comment: @frndsforever: If an answer has solved your problem, click on the check mark next to it to accept it, so that others coming to this post will know that it is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("p").each(function(a,b){
   if ($(this).html() == 'i'){
      console.log(a);
   }
});
```

or

```
$("p").filter(function(){
   return $(this).html() == 'i';
});
```

Comment: what is the need for passing a,b

Comment: a is numeral index which shows you place where "i" was found in

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the paragraphs and check if their content is the same as your desired content. I used a jQuery loop, you can use javascript if you want.
[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/qU8tu/)

```
$('p').each(function() {
    if(this.innerHTML == 'i') doWhateverYouWant();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a simple plugin for this:

```
$.fn.exactMatch = function(str) {
    return this.filter(function() {
        return $(this).text() === str;
    });
};

$("p").exactMatch("i").css("border", "1px solid red");
```

[**You can try it here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/karim79/TVt6M/)